# How to avoid overriding hstore records by other people in simple landing sign up forms?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, hstore

I want to build a simple site with various number of landing pages which have different forms

Example with two fields: `email` and `zipcode`

Each form has `email` field and random number of other fields: `first_name`, `city` ...

I am wondering about use `hstore` for completing properties for each email because
I don't want to have multiple records with the same email and other properties.

I have only one concern, How would be good pattern to avoid the situation when other people are being able to override fields if they are know email address which already exist in database?

Comment: Add password protection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that hstore adds any new security issues.  The simple answer is to treat it like you would anything else, and check appropriate permissions.  For example you could add a password check for updating info relating to the email.

With security like this there are a large number of ways to do things.  Your first decision needs to be where to enforce security.  In the database?  In the web app?  etc.  From there, the security decisions should be relatively obvious.   For example, this determines where to check the password, and where to check that only the appropriate email can be updated.  The best answer here will depend on your environment.

If this is a simple web site you probably want to enforce appropriate behavior in the web app level.  The specifics will depend on your language of choice, etc.